# Show update dialog with Fabric Beta

Tags: android, google-fabric, fabric-beta

Is there any way to get last build version from Fabric Beta in Android? Or maybe is there any chance to show dialog like in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here.

There is not currently a public API to pull the latest build version from Beta. You could consider using fastlane in order to auto-increment build numbers by using: [increment_build_number](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/increment_build_number/#increment_build_number).